# Unable to create extent_report.html via automation using selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, testng, extent, extentreports

1. I am writing automation test case in java using selenium and TestNG.
2. I want to generate extent report using selenium and I wrote some code by referring the websites.
3. I don't get any errors, While running my automation test cases, But extent report is not get generated.

**Sample code for Extent Report Generation:**

```
@BeforeTest
    private void setup() throws Exception {
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(REPORTS_PATH + "/" + file_Prefix + "_extent.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig("src/test/resources/extent-config.xml");
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "SoftwareTestingMaterial");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Automation Testing");

        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Find Duplicates By Calculating Distance Between Lat/Long");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Automation Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);}
```

**Sample code for GetResult Method and End Report Method:**

```
@AfterMethod
public void getResult(ITestResult result) {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        // logger.log(Status.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getTestName());
        // MarkupHelper is used to display the output in different colors
        extentTest.log(Status.FAIL,
                MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getTestName() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
        extentTest.log(Status.FAIL,
                MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getThrowable() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
    }
}

@AfterTest
public void endReport() {
    File duplicate_File = new File(REPORTS_PATH + "/" + file_Prefix + "_duplicates.csv");
    try {
        FileUtils.writeLines(duplicate_File, duplicate_Pois, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Error writing to file " + e.getMessage());
    }
    extent.flush();
}
```

Comment: Where's your `extent.createTest()`?  I've added the **extent** and **extentreports** tags to this question so it gets included in those relevant groups.

Comment: Selenium has no way of generating any reports. Perhaps you meant: "...generate extent report using **java**..."?

Comment: I browsed lot and the above one is the best solution

Comment: @BillHileman, I missed the createTest() method, I am able to create report successfully. Thanks